# Несколько UITableView в одном ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Почему не происходит вызов после `else`?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    if (tableView == self.tabFourContacts)
    {

    NSLog(@"Сконфигурили 4 вкладку (контакты)");
    return cell;

    } else {

    NSLog(@"Сконфигурили 5 вкладку (отзывы)");
    return cell;
    }
}
```

**ОТВЕТ ЕСТЬ В КОММЕНТАРИИ:** **возвращается 0 в `numberofrowsinsection:`**

**Дополнительный вопрос**:
А это нормально, что при:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.tabFourContacts)
{
    NSLog(@"numRowsForTab1: %d", contactsArray.count);
    return contactsArray.count;
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"numRowsForTab2: %d", feedbacksArray.count);
    return feedbacksArray.count;
}
}
```

В логах пишется по несколько раз:

```
2015-06-03 00:21:50.819 MyApp[29317:1132720] numRowsForTab1: 0
2015-06-03 00:21:50.820 MyApp[29317:1132720] numRowsForTab1: 0
2015-06-03 00:21:50.820 MyApp[29317:1132720] numRowsForTab2: 0
2015-06-03 00:21:50.821 MyApp[29317:1132720] numRowsForTab2: 0
2015-06-03 00:21:50.826 MyApp[29317:1132720] numRowsForTab2: 0
2015-06-03 00:21:50.826 MyApp[29317:1132720] numRowsForTab1: 0
2015-06-03 00:21:50.829 MyApp[29317:1132720] numRowsForTab2: 0
2015-06-03 00:21:50.829 MyApp[29317:1132720] numRowsForTab1: 1
```

?

Или это из-за плохого кода? Не было такого, пока не поменял загрузку JSON с AFnetworking.

Comment: Нужно больше деталей, ошибка точно не в приведенном вами коде. Во втором случае дело в том, что компилятор не может доказать, что любой путь вычислений завершится return-ом

Comment: Также, ИМХО вам лучше использовать таббар - тогда у каждой вкладки будет свой контроллер и вам не придется заморачиваться

Comment: По поводу таббара - спасибо за совет, обязательно учту в следующих проектах, но дело в том, что макет уже утвержден и переделать не представляется возможным. По поводу первого комментария - ошибка точно не в коде - это означает, что else обязательно должно работать в данном случае?

Comment: Да. Лучше всего используйте отладчик: поставьте брейкпойнт и посмотрите, какую table view вы получаете в каком случае.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что контроллер должен создавать Cell для каждой из  TableView одновременно (их две в одном контроллере).

Comment: Я понимаю, и? Вы хотите понять, почему метод не вызывается со второй таблицей? Посмотрите отладчиком все его вызовы, а также через capture view hierarchy убедитесь, что у всех таблиц корректно выставлен dataSource.

Comment: dataSource и deligate у этой таблицы (как и у другой, которая работает) выставлены на текущий контроллер. Не совсем понятно, что я должен отладчиком проверить - вызов каких всех его методов? Которые не запускаются? После else не отрабатывает... куда маркер не поставь.

Comment: `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`` - когда вы ожидаете, что он вызовется со второй таблицей? Вот тогда и проверяйте.

Comment: `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` может не вызываться, если метод `- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` возвращает 0. Проверьте, вызывается ли `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` для пятой таблицы и что он возвращает?

Comment: Верно подметили, возвращает 0... буду думать теперь почему у меня заполненный массив отзывов становится nil...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переношу из комментария в ответ:

`-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` может не вызываться, если метод `- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` возвращает 0. Проверьте, вызывается ли `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` для пятой таблицы и что он возвращает.

Не претендуя на истину, просто предположение по поводу количества вызовов `tableView:numberofrowsInSection:`: оно равно количеству вызовов `[tableView reloadData]`. Попробуйте посмотреть сколько раз вызываетcя `reloadData` в вашем коде, возможно это происходит не один раз.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что reloadData один раз вызывается...